# MockEndpoint doesnt count received message

Tags: java, spring, testing, apache-camel

When I start test route, my real endpoint receives message right, but MockEnpoint object doesnt increase receivedCount and test fails with:

> java.lang.AssertionError: mock://direct:test.ts.api.location Received
>   message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>

Route:

```
<route id="test_to_ts" autoStartup="true">
  <from uri="activemq:test.ts" />
  <choice>
    <when>
      <simple>${header.type} == 'location'</simple>
        <to uri="direct:test.ts.api.location" />
    </when>
    ...
  <choice>
</route>
```

Thats my test class:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/config/context.xml", loader= TestContextLoader.class)
@ShutdownTimeout(value = 30, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@MockEndpoints(value = "direct:test.ts.api.location")
public class RouteTest {    
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:test.ts.api.location")
    private MockEndpoint locationEndpont;

    @Produce(uri = "activemq:test.ts")
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testSendMessageTypeLocation() throws Exception {        
        String strBody = "body";

        locationEndpont.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        locationEndpont.setResultWaitTime(10000);
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:test.ts", strBody, "type", "location");

        locationEndpont.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
```

It looks for me like my mock is not linked with endpoint, but I cant see reason.

Spring version: 3.2.11 
Camel version: 2.13.3

UPD1: I removed annotations and made RouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport with overriding createApplicationContext(),isMockEndpoints() methods - this works.
Still dont understand what problem in my code with annotations

UPD2: Thats code after changes:

```
public abstract class AbstractRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {
protected String[] routesToStart;
protected String[] routeMocksPattern;
protected long result_wait_time = 1000;
protected long assert_period_time = 100;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
    boolean first = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("(");
    for (String mock : routeMocksPattern) {
        if (first) sb.append("|");
        sb.append(mock);
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
protected void startCamelContext() throws Exception {
    context().setAutoStartup(false);
    super.startCamelContext();

    for (String routeId : routesToStart) {
        context().startRoute(routeId);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isCreateCamelContextPerClass() {
    return true;
}

protected abstract AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext();
}
}
public class RouteTest extends AbstractRouteTest {
private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "src/test/resources/messages_test_to_ts/spring-test-context.xml";
private static final String START_ENDPOINT = "activemq:test.ts";

@Produce(uri = START_ENDPOINT)
private ProducerTemplate template;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:logdb:test")
private MockEndpoint logdbEndpoint;
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:test.ts.api.location")
private MockEndpoint locationEndpoint;

public MdmToTSLocationRouteTest() {
    routesToStart = new String[] {"test_to_ts", "test_ts_api_location", "log_the_error"};
    routeMocksPattern = new String[] 
            {"(logdb:test.*sendToTS.*TEST_TO_TS.*(success).*)", "direct:test.ts.api.location"};
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    locationEndpoint.setResultWaitTime(result_wait_time);
    logdbEndpoint.setResultWaitTime(result_wait_time);

    locationEndpoint.setAssertPeriod(assert_period_time);
    logdbEndpoint.setAssertPeriod(assert_period_time);
}

@Test
public void testSendLocationMessage() throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
    String body = TestUtil.readFile("src/test/resources/messages_test_to_ts/location.xml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String expectedBody = TestUtil.readFile("src/test/resources/messages_test_to_ts/location_unmarshal.xml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\r", "");

    // set expectations 
    locationEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("type", "location");
    locationEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(body);
    locationEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);

    logdbEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("type", "location");
    logdbEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);
    logdbEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);

    // send message
    template.sendBodyAndHeader(body, "type", "location");

    // assert
    locationEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    logdbEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}

@Override
protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new TestContextLoader(CONTEXT_PATH).createApplicationContext();
    LocationUploader process = (LocationUploader) context.getBean("locationUploadBean");
    OracleDataSource oraDSMock = Mockito.mock(OracleDataSource.class);
    WrapperManager wrapperManagerMock = Mockito.mock(WrapperManager.class);
    Statement stmtMock = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
    OracleCallableStatement oraCSMock = Mockito.mock(OracleCallableStatement.class);
    Wrapper wrapperMock = Mockito.mock(Wrapper.class);
    Connection connMock = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    try {
        Mockito.when(oraDSMock.getConnection()).thenReturn(connMock);
        Mockito.when(connMock.createStatement()).thenReturn(stmtMock);
        Mockito.when(connMock.prepareCall(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(oraCSMock);
        Mockito.when(wrapperManagerMock.getWrapper(java.util.List.class, "ORA_SCHEME.T_TEST_LOCATION_TAB")).thenReturn(wrapperMock);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    process.setDataSource(oraDSMock);
    process.setManager(wrapperManagerMock);
    return context;
}
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and tried your suggested "workaround", but I get the same AssertionError. How does your test class look after the change?

Comment: Thanks! I got my test working with other suggestions, but not quite perfect.

Comment: How did you override `createApplicationContext()` in your `RouteTest` class?